# Proving $P(X \ge 0) = 1 \implies E(X) \ge 0$

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Show  that  if $P(X \ge 0)  =  1$,  then $E(X) \ge 0$.

I am aware that we need to prove this statement holds for the  discrete  and  continuous  cases separately, however, I am not quite sure how to.

For the discrete case, I know that $E(X) = \Sigma_{i}x_ip_{i}$. But, how can I use the fact $P(X \ge 0)  =  1$? I don't quite see.

Comment: One problematic aspect of this is that, for continuous variables, one could have $P(X\geq 0)=1$ without having $E(X)$ exist in the first place. For instance, take a half-Cauchy random variable, i.e., pdf $f(x)=\frac{2}{\pi}(1+x^2)^{-1}$ if $x\geq 0$ and $0$ otherwise. So presumably the point is that $E(X)$, if it exists, cannot be negative.

Comment: @Semiclassical -  There are also  discrete  non-negative random variables with infinite expectation too.  For example $P(X=n)=\frac{6}{\pi^2 n^2}$ with $n \in \{1,2,3,\ldots\}$

Comment: As noted $E(X)=+\infty$ is possible.

Comment: $E(X)=\int_\Omega X\,dP=\int_{(X<0)}X\,dP+\int_{(X\ge0})X\,dP=0+\int_{(X\ge0)}X\,dP\ge 0$.

Comment: @OP are you only concerned with the discrete and absolutely continuous case? In other words, your only concern is discrete rv and rv with densities? If so, both series and integral reduce to $\sum x_i p_i$ and $\int x f(x) dx,$ where the $x_i \geq 0$ since $P(X \geq 0) = 1$ and with the integral $f(x) = 0$ for $x < 0.$

Comment: @Semiclassical In that case, you have $E[X]=+\infty>0$ as claimed, so there is no problem. Infinity exists.

Answer (score 0):

By definition,
$$
\mathsf{E}X=\mathsf{E}X^+-\mathsf{E}X^-,
$$
whenever $\mathsf{E}X^+\wedge\mathsf{E}X^-<\infty$. (Here $X^+\equiv X\vee 0$ and $X^-\equiv -(X\wedge 0)$.) In your case $\mathsf{E}X^-=0$ ($\because$ $\mathsf{P}(X^-=0)=1$).

Comment: This is circular reasoning. How do you show $EX^+ \ge 0$?

Comment: $\mathsf{E}X^+\ge 0$ and $\mathsf{E}X^-\ge 0$ by construction ($X^+, X^-\in L^{+}$).

Comment: No, you have $X^+ \ge 0$ by construction what's nothing else then $P(X^+ \ge 0) = 1$ so the assumption given in the question.

Comment: The integral (expectation) of a nonnegative function $f$ is defined as
$$
\int f\equiv \sup\!\left\{\int \phi: 0\le \phi\le f, \phi\text{ is simple}\right\}\ge 0.
$$

Comment: I know how the integral of a non-negative function is defined, but this is additional arguing  which is missing in your answer. Actually this is THE argument why the expectation is non-negative and your decomposition is unnecessary.

Comment: $X$ in the question is not (necessarily) in $L^+$... Example: $([-1,1],\mathcal{B}_{[-1,1]},\mathsf{P})$, where $P([-1,0])=0$ and $\mathsf{P}((0,x])=x$ for $x>0$. Take $X(\omega)=\omega$.